# Using Automator to copy files, execute Cordova not working

Tags: macos, bash, shell, cordova, automator

I'm trying to create an Automator workflow which:

- gets files and folders of a directory
- copies those files and folders to another directory (with overwrite)
- run a shell command: cordova prepare

The issue i have is, I'm working in one folder and wanting to be able to run an application that does the above, rather than manually do it every time i need to refresh the Cordova app.

The first two of the above works fine, i see the files copy/overwrite as they should, but when it gets to the shell command it returns the error code "cordova - command not found (127)"

Is it because I have Cordova installed for my user only and it wont execute as root (or whatever OS X the Automator user is)? If so how would i get it to run as another user or install it globally?

I've tested a simple command such as "cd ~/Sites/ && open ./" which works fine without error. It's just the cordova not found thing which i have going on at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the cordova command, are you using the entire path to the Cordova app?  Something like this:

```
/Applications/Cordova.app
```